# Why was there no feedback post for the quarterly CEO blog post?

Tags: support, status-completed, blog

Yesterday, the quarterly CEO blog post was posted: "[Accelerating Stack Overflow’s transformation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/26/accelerating-stack-overflows-transformation/?_ga=2.115341383.1594360723.1619284263-1177248602.1577809698)"

Previously, there have been Meta.SE feedback posts where users could provide feedback and ask questions about the blog post, [such as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355909/294691). In fact, that post states "as always", indicating that this would be standard procedure for the CEO blog posts.

Why doesn't this one have any feedback post, then? I've already posted feedback in the form of a [separate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363743/294691), but I'm curious why there wasn't a main post this time. Have I misunderstood something about when a Meta.SE post would be provided?

Comment: Well the last time they invited people to leave feedback for the CEO’s post on meta, meta treated some of the people that accepted that invitation poorly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356384/273494 It’s probably better to just let people give their feedback with the reply form so staff can do the filtering instead of other customers.

Comment: The overall interest and approval to the quarterly posts seems to have dropped over the last year. I guess there was no desire to have another such Q&A. And it partly makes sense. One advantage of separate questions is that they are more focused. Tagging and searching all makes more sense for separate questions. With the "blog" tag and a link to the relevant blog post, such questions could be combined later, if desired.

Comment: Its also a very important sign that meta feedback matters - and the feedback question very much is a way show power users views are taken into account. I *guess* someone else could do it, but maaan, I hope we're past needing to sneak in feedback posts

Comment: I mean... Why present a feedback post to give the impression meta feedback matters... if it doesn't? At most it gets used to generate survey questions.

Answer (score -10):

Last quarter we decided to start having a community centric quarterly "State of the Stack" post from Teresa as the audience for the CEO post is mostly our customers. We thought it would be valuable to have Teresa speak directly to the community in a way that facilitates back and forth conversations. You can see Teresa’s first quarter post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361934/state-of-the-stack-q1-2021-blog-post). She will post a second quarter community centric post this quarter, and we will post a feedback thread on Meta.

Comment: So, it was done to decouple the userbase from the customerbase?