# 404: Q1 2022 Community team roadmap not found

Tags: support, community, roadmap

Since we are now on our way into the second month of the Q2 of 2022, it is time to address the elephant in the room: where is the Q1 2022 Community team roadmap? It hasn't been published on [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/community/); it hasn't been announced via a post with the [roadmap](/questions/tagged/roadmap) tag; there hasn't been an [MSE Feedback post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368049/786798) by the VP of Community.

On a related note... Where's the Q2 2022 roadmap?

Comment: @Catija is this concept of roadmap and sharing the plans even still alive? Or was it removed/changed as part of the acquisition too? (aka "orders from above")

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar there's no correlation between the acquisition and the publication of the information, as far as I'm aware. They don't seem to make any sort of edicts about things like that. I know people fear that some bogeyman is going to come out and change everything... but that's really not what's happening.

Comment: Apologies for the huge delay in responding to this. Even though we haven’t been doing public roadmaps for the past couple of years, we absolutely understand the desire to see the direction of the community team laid out in public. The company is currently engaged in annual planning, and our intent is to publish a description of the anticipated work for the year once the team’s strategy is nailed down. Be on the lookout for that!

Comment: @JNat will it be only published in the blog, without a meta post?

Comment: The current plan is to post on MSE, @ShadowWizardLoveZelda ;)